# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation in iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7

Below line of code nicely rotates my progress view in iOS 8. But in iOS 7, it messes up my view and 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' errors start popping.
Is it to be implemented differently in iOS 7 ?

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(270 * M_PI / 180.0))
```

Comment: Don't use autolayouts with animating view with CGAffineTransform or use subview without autolayouts or use sublayer/etc.

Comment: @rock88, you mean, don't use autolayout just for this progressView? Not using autolayout at all will be difficult.

Comment: yes, only for this view, just set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO and set frame for this view.

Comment: @rock88, I added this line above my CGAffin line but did not help 
progressView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

Comment: i just test this code on iOS7&8, all work (sorry for bad formatting)
        `var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(140, 140, 60, 160));
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
        view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
        self.view.addSubview(view);
        
        UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(270 * M_PI / 180.0));
        });`

Comment: @rock88, the difference is, my progressView is already in superview setup in storeyboard and has constraints set to other subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this little tutorial.
Looks like there is what you are looking for.
http://dev.mikamai.com/post/74941935186/rotating-an-uiview-around-an-arbitrary-point